# Implementing class-based query (query_property) in a zope transaction_manager system, is this testable?

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm using SQLAlchemy in a Pyramid system. I use a transaction manager (zope) and add a request_method called 'db_session', so request.session can be used to do queries.

This is fine in views, but for functions on my SQLAlchemy objects themselves I'm using inspect(self).session to get the session. This is fairly common as far as I can tell.

Now I want to be able to access my zope transaction session from classmethods on my SQLAlchemy objects. After trying various things, I realize I have to set my metaclass Base.query to Session.query_property() inside the includeme() function in **init**.py. Basically this:-

```
def includeme(config):

    settings = config.get_settings()

    # use pyramid_tm to hook the transaction lifecycle to the request
    config.include('pyramid_tm')

    session_factory = get_session_factory(get_engine(settings))

    factory = scoped_session(session_factory)
    config.registry['dbsession_factory'] = factory
    Base.query = factory.query_property()

    # make request.dbsession available for use in Pyramid
    config.add_request_method(
        # r.tm is the transaction manager used by pyramid_tm
        lambda r: get_tm_session(session_factory, r.tm),
        'dbsession',
        reify=True
    )
```

'Base' here is my metaclass.

This does what I want, but I realize what I'm effectively doing when using this is using a python global variable. I haven't proceeded very far yet, but is this going to cause problems (especially with testability) in future? I'm pretty sure it 'works' for what I want to do (classmethods have inherent access to the current session without having to have it passed to them).

Comment: I can't say for sure, but to me it looks like the query from `Base` will be outside of any transaction and may cause trouble, especially if you mix code that uses the transaction and code that does not.

Comment: That's possible, I can't claim to know too much about what's going on under the abstractions. How would I check that?

Comment: I guess you could try something like `request.dbsession.add(User(email='some@example.com'))` then the following line `User.query.filter(email='some@example.com').first()`. If it can't find it, it means they are in 2 separate transactions. But I can't be sure that if it finds it they are in the same transaction. One fix could be to implement a custom `query` method that accepts the `dbsession`, like `User.query(request.dbsession).etc()`, but it's not much different from `request.dbsession.query(User).etc()`.

Comment: Some testing based on your suggestions indicates that you're right, as User.query.all() returns something different from request.dbsession.query(User).all(). I've moved the setting of Base.query = query_property into get_tm_session, and this now seems to 'work' correctly. Not sure if I should edit my question (have asked a meta question about that) on that, but thanks!

Comment: Should you not pass transaction manager the scoped session factory (thread local session), not a plain session factory? Moving `Base.query = query_property` in to `get_tm_session` seems wrong; what if another thread does that while another is still doing its thing?

Comment: Note that a vanilla [basic layout](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/basiclayout.html) does the whole `get_tm_session` in a way that does not need a scoped (thread local) session. But if you're going to go the `Base.query` route, that's about as good as it gets. Now if you could produce a [mcve] where you show why exactly you even need to use a [query class property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session.query_property).

Comment: Furthermore the latest Pyramid tutorials should no longer set up `scoped_session` and it is being phased out as not a good practice.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I know, it does seem wrong to me, but I can't find any other way to replicate what inspect(self).session does, which is allow me to access the session that an object comes from (rather than passing requestion.dbsession in to a object's functions). In this case, that a class is registered to.

Comment: Ng Oon-Ee, what you want to do seems like an anti-pattern to me. I personally pass the `dbsession` to the functions. That `dbsession` is bound to the current transaction and it makes a lot of sense to do it that way instead of trying to rely on some global state in a threaded environment.

Comment: Good point. After more consideration and testing I realize this is almost certain to result in undefined behaviour and race conditions if I'm using the Base class. Would you like to put up a simple answer @AntoineLeclair?